# Which of these "internationalization" tags should be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I just merged "i18n" into "internationalization" (which seems straightforward).

We now have several related tags, some of which should probably be merged:

- [multilingual](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) - 61 Questions
- [internationalization](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) - 47 Questions
- [language](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) - 46 Questions
- [international](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international)- 10 Questions
- <s>[multiregion](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiregion) - 5 Questions</s>

Any opinions on which one(s) should remain and which one(s) should be merged?

Comment: I just merged [Tag:mutliregion] into [Tag:internationalization].  I'm not making other changes at this time due to lack of discussion and consensus.

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts so far:

- Multilingual should stay
- Language is ambiguous so I hesitate to make it a synonym of anything without further discussion
- Multiregion should become a synonym of internationalization (if we keep that one)

Comment: Problem with Multiregion, can't it also be used to describe nationalization too.

Comment: I believe the term we're looking for here is "l10n" or ["localization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) - nuanced difference.

Comment: The description of [Tag:language] is "questions about multiple human languages", while the description of [Tag:multilingual] is IMO over-long and over-specific. Replace the long description with the short one and make language into a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in favor of merging all of the tags into "internationalization".

Looking through the questions that are tagged with the variants, all of them would work well with an "internationalization" tag.